Calculating the net forces in multi-mass dynamic system
I am trying to figure out a generalized method for finding the net force of each mass in a multi-mass dynamic system. We have learned methods in highschool but those don't work for more complex examples.
Consider the following example:

There are four masses, each connected by a rope (the connection point where the mass connects to the rope can move around the mass, I'm not evil). The rightmost mass (m1) is getting pulled the right at 100N. Just for clarity, I expect that the masses will straighten out as the 100N continues to pull from the right.
How would you go about finding the net force of each mass in this system? I already have a method in my mind, but its very tedious and I want to be able to generalize it for coding purposes. Does anyone know how this can be solved?

Do you really mean you want it for coding?  When coding, we usually use approximations.  What you want can be solved for perfectly, but we tend not to do it that way in code.

Its less fore the coding and more for my own learning, the code will just be a way for me to visualize and showcase my work. How would you approach solving it?

Voting to reopen. Obviously not a homework question since the problem is much too difficult for that.

@KhalilBurns Consider the accelerated frame of the first mass. In this frame there will be a fictitious acceleration backwards. So the system will behave like a triple pendulum.

@gandalf61 The close reason isn't "this is an assigned homework problem".

@BioPhysicist It recently looked like a homework problem but I have since updated it to generalize it more

I launched my master's thesis in 1996 with this exact question (except for rigid bodies).

@KhalilBurns - for modeling you can look at this Julia Notebook that deals with the impact response from a serial chain of rigid bodies (that is grounded).

Dynamics Using Vectors
What you are missing is the kinematics, as the allowed motion of one body depends on the motion of the previous body.
I am designating $\vec{r}_i$ the position vector of the i-th body, and its derivatives $\vec{v}_i$ the velocity of the body and $\vec{a}_i$ the acceleration of the body.
Let us look at the linkage between the 1st and 2nd body. The distance must remain constant at all times.
The distance squared function is evaluated with the following dot product
$$\left(\vec{r}_{2}-\vec{r}_{1}\right)\cdot\left(\vec{r}_{2}-\vec{r}_{1}\right)=\text{<const>} \tag{1}$$
and differentiating the above gives us
$$2\left(\vec{v}_{2}-\vec{v}_{1}\right)\cdot\left(\vec{r}_{2}-\vec{r}_{1}\right)=0 \tag{2} $$
The solution of the above represents the velocity kinematics and has the form of
$$\vec{v}_{2}-\vec{v}_{1}=\vec{\omega}_{12}\times\left(\vec{r}_{2}-\vec{r}_{1}\right) \tag{3}$$
where $\vec{\omega}_{12}$ is introduced to represent the rotation of the massless rod connecting bodies 1 and 2.
In 2D the  above equation is written out by component as
$$ \vec{v}_2 - \vec{v}_1 = \pmatrix{ \mbox{-}(y_2-y_1)\omega_{12} \\ (x_2-x_1)\omega_{12} }  $$
Taking one more derivative of (3) we get the acceleration kinematics
$$ \vec{a}_2 - \vec{a}_1 = \vec{\alpha}_{12}\times\left(\vec{r}_{2}-\vec{r}_{1}\right) + \vec{\omega}_{12}\times\left(\vec{v}_{2}-\vec{v}_{1}\right) \tag{4}$$
where $\vec{\alpha}_{12}$ is the rotational acceleration of the link between (1) and (2).
The 2D version of the above is
$$ \vec{a}_2 - \vec{a}_1= \pmatrix{ 
  \mbox{-}(y_2-y_1) \alpha_{12} - (x_2-x_1) \omega_{12}^2 \\
   (x_2-x_1) \alpha_{12} - (y_2-y_1) \omega_{12}^2 } $$
and similarly for the remaining two rods
$$ \vec{a}_3 - \vec{a}_2= \pmatrix{ 
  \mbox{-}(y_3-y_2) \alpha_{23} - (x_3-x_2) \omega_{23}^2 \\
   (x_3-x_2) \alpha_{23} - (y_3-y_2) \omega_{23}^2 } $$
and
$$ \vec{a}_4 - \vec{a}_3= \pmatrix{ 
  \mbox{-}(y_4-y_3) \alpha_{34} - (x_4-x_3) \omega_{34}^2 \\
   (x_4-x_3) \alpha_{34} - (y_4-y_3) \omega_{34}^2 } $$
Since there are 3 rods, there are three acceleration kinematics, for a total of 6 equations by component. The unknowns so far are the 8 acceleration components for the 4 masses, and the 3 rotational acceleration components $\alpha_{12}$, $\alpha{23}$ and $\alpha{34}$ for the rods, for a total of 11 unknown quantities.
Now we introduce Newton's equations of motion which depend on the (scalar) axial forces  $\vec{F}_{ij}$ developed in the rod connecting masses i and j as well as the external force $\vec{F}_{1}^{\rm ext} $ acting on body 1.
Let us look at the axial force between bodies 1 and 2. The force vector is along the direction going from 1 to 2, and acting in a positive manner on body 2.
$$\vec{F}_{12}=\frac{\vec{r}_{2}-\vec{r}_{1}}{\|\vec{r}_{2}-\vec{r}_{1}\|}F_{12} \tag{5}$$
where $F_{12}$ a scalar force magnitude. Note that moving forward we are going to introduce notation $\ell_{12} = \|\vec{r}_{2}-\vec{r}_{1}\|$ for the length between the masses.
The equations of motion for body 1 must account for this force in a negative fashion, and for body 2 in positive fashion, due to Newton's 3rd law.
$$\begin{aligned}\vec{F}_{1}^{{\rm ext}}-\vec{F}_{12} & =m_{1}\vec{a}_{1}\\
\vec{F}_{12}-\vec{F}_{23} & =m_{2}\vec{a}_{2}\\
\vec{F}_{23}-\vec{F}_{34} & =m_{3}\vec{a}_{3}\\
\vec{F}_{34} & =m_{4}\vec{a}_{4}
\end{aligned} \tag{6}$$
In 2D the equations for body 1 are
$$\begin{pmatrix}\mbox{-}\frac{x_{2}-x_{1}}{\ell_{12}}F_{12}+F_{x}^{{\rm ext}}\\
\mbox{-}\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{\ell_{12}}F_{12}+F_{y}^{{\rm ext}}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}m\ddot{x}_{1}\\
m\ddot{y}_{1}
\end{pmatrix}$$ where $\ell_{12} = \sqrt{(x_{2}-x_{1})^{2}+(y_{2}-y_{1})^{2}}$ is the distance between the masses, $\ddot{x}_1$ the x-axis component of the acceleration of body 1, and $\ddot{y}_1$ the y-axis component of the acceleration of body 1.
For the remaining 3 bodies the equations have the following form
$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{x_{2}-x_{1}}{\ell_{12}}F_{12}-\frac{x_{3}-x_{2}}{\ell_{23}}F_{23}\\
\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{\ell_{12}}F_{12}-\frac{x_{3}-x_{2}}{\ell_{23}}F_{12}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}m\ddot{x}_{2}\\
m\ddot{y}_{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
These are now 4 vector equations (or 8 component equations), and they introduce 3 unknown quantities $F_{12}$, $F_{23}$ and $F_{34}$
So in total, there are 8+3+3 = 14 unknowns, and 6+8 = 14 equations. The problem is solvable using linear algebra.
Kinematics
The 6 acceleration kinematics equations can be summarized in linear algebra using vectors and matrices as
$$\small \begin{bmatrix}\text{-}1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & \text{-}1 & 0 & 1\\
 &  & \text{-}1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
 &  & 0 & \text{-}1 & 0 & 1\\
 &  &  &  & \text{-}1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
 &  &  &  & 0 & \text{-}1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\ddot{x}_{1}\\
\ddot{y}_{1}\\
\ddot{x}_{2}\\
\ddot{y}_{2}\\
\ddot{x}_{3}\\
\ddot{y}_{3}\\
\ddot{x}_{4}\\
\ddot{y}_{4}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\mbox{-}(y_{2}-y_{1})\\
(x_{2}-x_{1})\\
 & \mbox{-}(y_{3}-y_{2})\\
 & (x_{3}-x_{2})\\
 &  & \mbox{-}(y_{4}-y_{3})\\
 &  & (x_{4}-x_{3})
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_{12}\\
\alpha_{23}\\
\alpha_{34}
\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}(x_{2}-x_{1})\omega_{12}^{2}\\
(y_{2}-y_{1})\omega_{12}^{2}\\
(x_{3}-x_{2})\omega_{23}^{2}\\
(y_{3}-y_{2})\omega_{23}^{2}\\
(x_{4}-x_{3})\omega_{23}^{2}\\
(y_{4}-y_{3})\omega_{23}^{2}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Dynamics
The 8 equations of motion are summarized using linear algebra with vectors and matrices as
$$\small \begin{bmatrix}\text{-}\frac{x_{2}-x_{1}}{\ell_{12}}\\
\text{-}\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{\ell_{12}}\\
\frac{x_{2}-x_{1}}{\ell_{12}} & \mbox{-}\frac{x_{3}-x_{2}}{\ell_{23}}\\
\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{\ell_{12}} & \mbox{-}\frac{y_{3}-y_{2}}{\ell_{23}}\\
 & \frac{x_{3}-x_{2}}{\ell_{23}} & \mbox{-}\frac{x_{4}-x_{3}}{\ell_{34}}\\
 & \frac{y_{3}-y_{2}}{\ell_{23}} & \mbox{-}\frac{y_{4}-y_{3}}{\ell_{34}}\\
 &  & \frac{x_{4}-x_{3}}{\ell_{34}}\\
 &  & \frac{y_{4}-y_{3}}{\ell_{34}}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}F_{12}\\
F_{23}\\
F_{34}
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}F_{x}^{{\rm ext}}\\
F_{y}^{{\rm ext}}\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}m_{1}\\
 & m_{1}\\
 &  & m_{2}\\
 &  &  & m_{2}\\
 &  &  &  & m_{3}\\
 &  &  &  &  & m_{3}\\
 &  &  &  &  &  & m_{4}\\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  & m_{4}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\ddot{x}_{1}\\
\ddot{y}_{1}\\
\ddot{x}_{2}\\
\ddot{y}_{2}\\
\ddot{x}_{3}\\
\ddot{y}_{3}\\
\ddot{x}_{4}\\
\ddot{y}_{4}
\end{bmatrix}$$

The full system of equations is
$$\small \begin{bmatrix}\text{-}\frac{x_{2}-x_{1}}{\ell_{12}} &  &  &  &  &  & \text{-}m_{1}\\
\text{-}\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{\ell_{12}} &  &  &  &  &  &  & \text{-}m_{1}\\
\frac{x_{2}-x_{1}}{\ell_{12}} & \mbox{-}\frac{x_{3}-x_{2}}{\ell_{23}} &  &  &  &  &  &  & \text{-}m_{2}\\
\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{\ell_{12}} & \mbox{-}\frac{y_{3}-y_{2}}{\ell_{23}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \text{-}m_{2}\\
 & \frac{x_{3}-x_{2}}{\ell_{23}} & \mbox{-}\frac{x_{4}-x_{3}}{\ell_{34}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \text{-}m_{3}\\
 & \frac{y_{3}-y_{2}}{\ell_{23}} & \mbox{-}\frac{y_{4}-y_{3}}{\ell_{34}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \text{-}m_{3}\\
 &  & \frac{x_{4}-x_{3}}{\ell_{34}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \text{-}m_{4}\\
 &  & \frac{y_{4}-y_{3}}{\ell_{34}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \text{-}m_{4}\\
\hline  &  &  & (y_{2}-y_{1}) &  &  & \text{-}1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
 &  &  & \text{-}(x_{2}-x_{1}) &  &  & 0 & \text{-}1 & 0 & 1\\
 &  &  &  & (y_{3}-y_{2}) &  &  &  & \text{-}1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
 &  &  &  & \text{-}(x_{3}-x_{2}) &  &  &  & 0 & \text{-}1 & 0 & 1\\
 &  &  &  &  & (y_{4}-y_{3}) &  &  &  &  & \text{-}1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
 &  &  &  &  & \text{-}(x_{4}-x_{3}) &  &  &  &  & 0 & \text{-}1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}F_{12}\\
F_{23}\\
F_{34}\\
\hline \alpha_{12}\\
\alpha_{23}\\
\alpha_{34}\\
\hline \ddot{x}_{1}\\
\ddot{y}_{1}\\
\ddot{x}_{2}\\
\ddot{y}_{2}\\
\ddot{x}_{3}\\
\ddot{y}_{3}\\
\ddot{x}_{4}\\
\ddot{y}_{4}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\text{-}F_{x}^{{\rm ext}}\\
\text{-}F_{y}^{{\rm ext}}\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
\hline \text{-}(x_{2}-x_{1})\omega_{12}^{2}\\
\text{-}(y_{2}-y_{1})\omega_{12}^{2}\\
\text{-}(x_{3}-x_{2})\omega_{23}^{2}\\
\text{-}(y_{3}-y_{2})\omega_{23}^{2}\\
\text{-}(x_{4}-x_{3})\omega_{23}^{2}\\
\text{-}(y_{4}-y_{3})\omega_{23}^{2}
\end{bmatrix}$$
but creating a systematic way of solving these problems using vector notation is rather tedious and problematic.

Introduction to Rigid Body Dynamics using Vector Notation

Screw Dynamics
In a presentation I made I put forth the concepts needed to understand the kinematics and dynamics of rigid bodies using Screw Vectors which are 6 component vectors that embed the translational and rotational aspects of the quantities involved and have a geometric interpretation that is lacking from the vector notation.

Introduction to rigid body dynamics and kinematics using screw theory notation

Furthermore, using the concepts of Screw Theory assembling models and solving systems of multiple bodies becomes much less tedious. In the presentation below I go over the basic concepts needed to tackle a serial chain of rigid bodies.

Introduction to multibody dynamics and kinematics using screw theory.


Link to my thesis and my thesis presentation which outlines the use of screw theory to deal with chains of rigid bodies.

Please note the updated answer above. If needed, now that I read your question more carefully, I can expand on the modeling aspects of multibody systems even though it might be considered off-topic for this forum.

I really appreciate your answer, I'm still in highschool so it will probably take me a while to fully understand your answer, but this is super useful, much appreciated!

@KhalilBurns - that is amazing that you are curious enough to ask this great question. What you can take is that beyond $F = ma$ things get complicated really fast. In your, attempt to solve and model this problem, it is ok if you do not get it correctly, as the process matters more than the result. AND DO NOT BE DISCOURAGED as this is a graduate-level are of active research and you might want to look at some online resourced first on rigid body dynamics in order to start understanding some of the concepts.

$ \def \b {\mathbf} $

Static case
for each node you know the position vector
\begin{align*}
&\b R_i=\begin{bmatrix}
          x_i \\
          y_i\\
        \end{bmatrix}\quad, i=1\ldots~,n
\end{align*}
from here the constrained equations
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\b R_{i+1}-\b R_i\right)^2-L_i^2=0\quad, i=1\ldots,n-1\tag 1
\end{align*}
thus  the time derivative of equation (1)
\begin{align*}
 &2\,\left(\b R_{i+1}-\b R_i\right)^T\,\left(\b{\dot{ R}}_{i+1}-\b{\dot{ R}}_i\right)=0\quad, i=1\ldots,n-1\tag 2
\end{align*}
equation (2) your example
\begin{align*}
   &\left(\b R_2-\b R_1\right)^T\,\left(\b{\dot{ R}}_{2}-\b{\dot{ R}}_1\right)=0\\
   &\left(\b R_3-\b R_2\right)^T\,\left(\b{\dot{ R}}_{3}-\b{\dot{ R}}_2\right)=0\\
   &\left(\b R_4-\b R_3\right)^T\,\left(\b{\dot{ R}}_{4}-\b{\dot{ R}}_3\right)=0
 \end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
  &\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
     -\left(\b R_2-\b R_1\right)^T & \left(\b R_2-\b R_1\right)^T & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & -\left(\b R_3-\b R_2\right)^T & \left(\b R_3-\b R_2\right)^T & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & -\left(\b R_4-\b R_3\right)^T & \left(\b R_4-\b R_3\right)^T \\
   \end{bmatrix}}_{\b C_c~(3\times 8)}\,
   \begin{bmatrix}
     \b{\dot{R}}_1 \\
     \b{\dot{R}}_2 \\
     \b{\dot{R}}_3 \\
     \b{\dot{R}}_4 \\
   \end{bmatrix}=\b 0
 \end{align*}
external  force components   $~\b F~(8\times 1)$
\begin{align*}
  &\b F=\begin{bmatrix}
          0 \\
          0 \\
          0 \\
         0 \\
          0 \\
        0 \\
          F_{4x} \\
        F_{4y} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
 \end{align*}
for a static case you can use this equation
\begin{align*}
   &\b C_c^T\,\b \lambda+\b F=\b 0\quad\Rightarrow
  \end{align*}
\begin{align*}  
   &\underbrace{\left[\b C_c\,\b C_c^T\right]}_{(3 \times 3)}\,\b \lambda=-\underbrace{\b C_c\,\b F}_{(3\times1)}\tag 3
 \end{align*}
from equation (3) you obtain $~\b \lambda~$ ,thus  the nodes  force components $~\b f_i~(8\times 1)$ are
\begin{align*}
   &\b f=\b C^T_c\,\b\lambda
 \end{align*}
